# Sql select statement not working WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm working on a WPF where i have an sql statement to connect to the database.The statement is to search for First_Quater which it does but when i change to Second_Quater (which is not in the data base yet) It will give me the First_quater figuers. I can not get it to add just the First_Quater up in the column.

I have tryed so much and searched the internet but I'm still at a loss.
Thank you for your help.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=; Initial Catalog=; Integrated Security=True; Trusted_Connection=yes");
        con.Open();

        String comboquery = (@"SELECT * FROM [taxi_comm] WHERE First_Quarter = '" + checkedListBox1.SelectedItem + "'");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comboquery, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();




            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < gvDisplay.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {


                switch (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())
                {
                    case "First Quarter":

                        foreach (string s in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                        {

                            sum += Convert.ToInt32(gvDisplay.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
                            txtTotalGST.Text = sum.ToString(); 
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Its feb");
                        break;
                    case "Second Quarter":

                        foreach (string st in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                        {
                            sum += Convert.ToInt32(gvDisplay.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
                            txtTotalGST.Text = sum.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the second quarter");
                        }

                        break;
```

Comment: Use parameters in your query, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx To solve your problem, use debugging and watch or local window in Visual Studio.

Comment: where are you using the reader dr !!!

Comment: i have read that before im not sending data to the database i want to get it from the database. Yes i have debugged and the select works fine but will not change when the Second Quarter is checked it still reads the First_Quarter that is my problem. Heaps of info about fill the check list but not what i want i want the other way.

Comment: Why does it still read the First_Quarter?  What's the value of checkedListBox1.SelectedItem when the Second Quarter is checked?

Comment: Yes it reads first quarter when checked and second quarter  when checked when i debug. I just did a de bug then and the foreach loop only goes throught 6 times when i have 11 columns so I'm guessing its something with my foreach loop.

Comment: sorry about this but i read it wrong i was looking at the rows not columns so the foreach loop is good

Comment: As mentioned before, you need to debug this yourself to find the problem.  There is far too little information here for anyone to tell you what the problem is.  Step through it and check that the values you expect are coming from the database, and check that the application is summing the values you want, in the way you expect.  If you do that logically and diligently, you'll find out what's going wrong.

Comment: i have tryed debugging it it does what it is to do expect for the sum which is to add column 10 up but for some reason now it will not do that just gives me  0 every time so its something to do with my maths not sure what but Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your help work it out all working fine How do you mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate your gvdisplay from the query

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comboquery, con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable gvdisplay = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(gvdisplay);

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gvdisplay.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {


            switch (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())
            {
                case "First Quarter":

                    foreach (string s in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                    {

                        sum += Convert.ToInt32(gvdisplay.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
                        txtTotalGST.Text = sum.ToString(); 
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Its feb");
                    break;
                case "Second Quarter":
//.......//
```